# I need an adaptor to read my old laptop harddisk

Tags: hard-drive, sata, laptop

I want to find an adaptor that will allow me to read my old [Laptop harddrive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilbdx.jpg). Can someone help me find the right adaptor for this?

Comment: I would suggest starting with google. It's not a *high* bar to cross.

Comment: yes, i agree with vidarlo, google is your friend

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is an M.2 NVMe drive. You need to plug in those keywords, plus perhaps "USB adapter" to find an appropriate product.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the trick:

https://www.orico.cc/us/product/detail/7207.html

Comment: Product Suggestions are offtopic

Comment: That would be why I closed it as offtopic, yes.